# How do i set a source in my asp.net page with database?

Tags: asp.net, database

i would like to know how to define my source in my ASP.NET code.
I have a database with tables but i dont know how to connect them to my project, also which libraries do i need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
                string connection, sql;
                connection = @"Data Source=DEVICE\SERVICE; Initial Catalog=database; Integrated Security=True";
                sql = your query;
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                conn.Open();
                int succes= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
```

Use these libraries if you want to use the previously stated commands:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your database values in a table, try this:

```
conn.Open();
cmd = "SELECT * FROM database";
SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn);
DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
dataadapter.Fill(datatable);
yourGridview.DataSource = datatable;
yourGridview.DataBind();
conn.Close();
```

if you would like to store new items in your database via your asp project, do this:

```
cmd = "insert into database values(your values)";
conn.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, conn);
_result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

make sure you have this snippet of code at "public partial class":

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = DEVICE\SERVICE; InitialCatalog = database; Integrated Security = True");
string cmd;
int _result = 0;
```